# Find changes to string variable name that have been committed using bzr

Tags: bash, version-control, grep, bazaar

At some point, the calculation of a parameter, `parmX` was changed in my code. How can I find out who, when, and why the change was made? `grep -ir parmX .bzr/` returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the .bzr is in compressed format, so standard grep has trouble searching through it.

Maybe you should checkout the bazaar grep plugin: I allows you to grep through the repository. Also with revision constrains etc: https://launchpad.net/bzr-grep